# Beginner in html/css: Why do web pages have so many levels of divs?Why not define all properties in one class?

Tags: html, css, web

In every web page there is a div inside a div inside a div inside a div...never ending pool of divs. and they all have their ids or classes. Why is it done like this. Why not define all properties in one place? What is the significance of this technique?

```
    <div id="body-top">
      <div id="body-bot">
        <div id="about-box">
          <h2><b>About</b> our music</h2>
          <img src="images/pic_1.jpg" width="112" height="92" alt="Pic 1" class="left" />
          <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </li>
            <li>Cras semper erat ut mi. </li>
            <li>Proin lobortis ipsum ac erat. </li>
            <li>Morbi nec enim vitae est posuere luctus.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="express-box">
          <h2><b>Express</b> Learning</h2>
          <img src="images/pic_2.jpg" width="112" height="92" alt="Pic 2" class="left" />
          <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
          <div class="narrow-text">
            <p><a href="#">It is a long</a> established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
            <p><a href="#">The point of using</a> Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters...</p>
          </div>
          <p class="more"><a href="#"><img src="images/more.gif" width="68" height="14" alt="More" /></a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="foot">
    <div id="foot-top">
      <div id="foot-bot">
        <div id="what-box">
          <h2><b>What</b> we offer</h2>
          <img src="images/pic_3.jpg" width="86" height="77" alt="Pic 3" class="left" />
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a> dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Cras semper erat ut mi. </li>
            <li>Proin lobortis ipsum ac erat. </li>
            <li>Morbi nec enim vitae est posuere luctus.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="news-box">
          <h2><b>News</b> &amp; events</h2>
          <img src="images/pic_4.jpg" width="86" height="77" alt="Pic 4" class="left" />
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nullam</a> scelerisque consequat libero. </li>
            <li><a href="#">Vivamus</a> mattis augue ut augue.</li>
          </ul>
          <p class="more clear"><a href="#"><img src="images/more.gif" width="68" height="14" alt="More" /></a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "define all properties in one place"? Are you suggesting that there should only be one class?

Comment: @mason one attribute can have multiple classes. sometimes there's only one or two elements buried in a lot of divs all of which have their ids. i just need help with explanation on this technique? for example: the code in description

Comment: No, attributes cannot have classes. Only elements can have classes. Divs are just containers to contain styling or group components.

Comment: You can have a type of inheritance though within your elements, so fro example, all `span` within class `narrow-text` can be of one styling, I can't think of any other way this could be made more efficient.

Also remember HTML is just a markup language..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use an analogy.

Lets say you are designing the layout of a house.

You divide the total area of the house into smaller sections (first level of divs). These sections are your different rooms (classes/ids you give to divs).

```
<body>
    <div class="bedroom room"></div>
    <div class="bedroom room"></div>
    <div class="kitchen room">
    </div>
    <div class="washroom room"></div>
</body>
```

Then lets say the kitchen will need a several items in it that get their own section/space in the kitchen (second level of divs). Items such as the fridge, sink, stovetop, etc (classes/ids).

```
        <div class="kitchen room">
            <div class="kitchenItem" id="fridge"></div>
            <div class="kitchenItem" id="stove"></div>
            <div class="kitchenItem" id="sink"></div>
        </div>
```

You can go as detailed as you like in your breakdown of the elements in each section of the house, similarly thats how a webpage is designed with divs and those divs are then given classes and ids.

Now lets say all your rooms have the same type of color, so with CSS, you can apply this common styling using:

```
.room{
    //your common styles here
    background-color: white;
}
```

But lets say now a design change comes around and you want your bedrooms to be painted blue instead of white. So you use the second class `bedroom` to change the CSS for all the bedrooms:

```
.room.bedroom{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

EDIT:

People use `div`s since they are one of the most general elements in HTML. They essentially give no context of what they contain. Just like in the house, they just signify space in the house. While other elements like `p`, `h1`, `h2`, etc  give a context that it will contain some text.

Comment: thanks...i think i am getting somewhere... ;)
if i have defined some property in an outer div...will defining it again with some other value override the outer one or does the outer one gets more preference?

Comment: What you are talking about is called CSS specificity. You can learn about it here: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @Just.Programmer can you also give an example of what you mean?

Comment: <div style="color: red;">
                    <div style="color: black;"></div></div>
which one actually gets applied?red or black?

Comment: i think its black tho

Comment: @Just.Programmer please read over the link I sent. 
Since the child div has another inline style applied to it, it will get higher priority over the parent div's style. Hence it will be black

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's because maybe you want to have 2 Divs like

```
<div class="A">
 <div class="B">
  <p> content
 </div>
</div>
```

But now DIV B should have other properties than DIV A, for example the width, or background color. 
If you use this structure for all HTML Documents, and if you always code like this style, with this insets, it's easy to see wich DIV is where on your Page, and what its for. That's not that clear with only a few DIVs.

Answer (score -1):

Html and therefore divs are for styling/visual look.

Each look can look as simple or as complex as one can imagine...

Therefore to create this it requires different techniques to archive these looks.

Nesting devs is to archive a look and nothing to do with holding properties.

Hope that makes sense... but that is the simplest way to explain it.

Comment: comment-less people should be banned. What was wrong about this and where is your input?

Comment: I wasn't the one to down vote but saying that HTML is for `styling` is not correct. That's what CSS is for. HTML elements are specifically content holders...they give a context of what content they will be holding.

Comment: @stackErr yes yes... but try do it with out HTML, also i didn't quite word it like that.... I said, divs are for styling... in that you need them to archive the style.... now we getting to in what i mean by style, I mean the Look! Try creating the Look with no divs... the look is achieved with divs. I know what your saying tho. But in a nut shell... divs are used as building blocks to help achieve a look.. which is what i was saying.

Comment: You can create really well designed webpages without divs. Don't abuse them.  Divs serve a very general purpose. They should be used when no other html element can describe the function of the content it is enclosing.

Comment: You might want to read this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

Comment: This is in fact correct. If there is no HTML, there is no visual part. Could almost say a blank page.

Comment: @stackErr still doesn't change the fact that 98% of nesting div on the internet today are used to archive a look... nothing more. Also with out html you just have text.. why use html... well a number of reasons... but why nest them in weird ways.. to position element where you want them to appear on the page.

Comment: @Seabizkit ok understood and agreed! :D